# What should be the provisioning model?

Tags: 2010, site-definition, web-template, provisioning

What should be the provisioning model for supporting only 2010 and above, if:

- it needs to include custom SharePoint security groups
- it would be deployed to multiple unrelated SharePoint installations

I have a feeling only site definition would support these, but could more experienced please comment?

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question but if you only need to provision security groups why not just use a feature which makes the appropriate modifications?

You may need to think how you decide what the custom security groups would be called. Unless they are always the same. One option could be defining feature properties.

Comment: Are there custom master pages withbdesign being implemented as well?

Comment: My bad, I did not include the details. These groups are needed along with other custom artifacts that would be bundled as a site-template/site-definition/something...

Comment: thanks - ok some more questions. will you have multiple sites created in site collection? do you expect people will use your solution in its own site collection? or mix with other types of sites. just thinking if you will have control at site collection level.

Comment: Most probably it would be only one instance in a particular site collection, but need not necessarily have to be at the site collection scope.